# Thread-safe negated AtomicBoolean get() as a condition in a while loop

Tags: java, multithreading

Suppose I have the following code:

```
AtomicBoolean condition;
condition = new AtomicBoolean(false);
(...)
while(!condition.get()){
   // do some stuff
}
```

I know that `condition.get()` is [atomic](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicBoolean.html#get()), but, is `!condition.get()` atomic as well?

I mean, could it happen that one `Thread` read the boolean value atomically and then it were interrupted before applying the `!` operation, so that another `Thread` gets into the loop before? If that's the case, would it be better to use a function such as:

```
private synchronized boolean checkNegatedCondition(AtomicBoolean cond){
    return !cond.get();
}

(...)

while(checkNegatedCondition(condition)){
   // do some stuff
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: *so that another Thread gets into the loop before?*: that has nothing to do with booleans and AtomicBooleans. There is no guaranteed order in which two threads enter such a loop. Whether you use a AtomicBoolean, and the ! operator, doesn't change anything to the order in which thread enter the loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Atomicity isn't the issue.
Two threads can read an atomic variable concurrently.
So any number of threads could read the value and enter the loop based on its negation. It doesn't matter if ! is atomic. It acts on a thread-local value.

To use atomics for exclusion you usually need `AtomicBoolean.compareAndSet(boolean,boolean)`.

`v.compareAndSet(a,b)` will only set `v` to value `b` if it is `a` and return true. Otherwise if v doesn't have the value `a` at the start, it does nothing and returns false.

In pseudo-code it's

```
 synchronized public boolean compareAndSet(boolean a,boolean b){
      if(v!=a) return false;
      v=b;
      return true;
 }
```

But (very important) takes place atomically so all other operations on v can be ordered before or after it.

```
AtomicBoolean condition = new AtomicBoolean(false);
//...
if(condition.compareAndSet(false,true)){
   //Only one thread can get here unless condition is set back...
}
```

if you wanted to use this as a 'pseudo' synchronized block you might code:

```
while(!condition.compareAndSet(false,true));
   //Only one thread can get here at a time...
 condition.set(false);
```

This could be described as'spin' locking. Because threads 'waiting' to enter the controlled section 'spin' round and round in the loop until released.
This may show poorer performance than `synchronized` because that operating system will normally 'suspend' waiting threads and progress other tasks.
However spin-locks can show better performance in cases where contention is very low (i.e. little or no waiting is required).

Pro-Tip: In practice it is good practice to put `condition.set(false) in a`finally` block:

```
while(!condition.compareAndSet(false,true));
try {
   //Only one thread can get here at a time...
 }finally{
     condition.set(false);
 }
```

Otherwise an exception thrown in one thread will permanently `lock out` any access to that section of code.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So in this case I understand that the code inside the `if` would be very similar to a synchronized block.

Comment: @yet_another_programmer I've edited the answer to show how you might use an atomic as a 'spin lock' to act like 'synchronized'.

Answer (score 4):

One has to be precise here:

- the result of the `get()` operation is supposed to be atomic, and because of the "further" guarantees for any atomic class, it is also guaranteed to be "visible" to *other* threads looking at the same object (atomic in the sense that all the **set* methods are *atomic*, so it is not possible to `get()` something that is "half-set")
- whereas the ! operation is **not** protected in any way

And just to be sure: the core thing here is *not* "atomicity" - because a `get()` just returns a value (and in contrast to a double, there is even just a single bit/byte affected). In other words: `AtomicBoolean` is mainly about making sure that changes to the object are visible to **all** threads using the object.

Buty yes, *assuming* that *AtomicBoolean* is a **field** of a class, and multiple threads are calling a method like:

```
public void foo() {
  while(!condition.get() ...
```

it is *theoretically* possible that

- Thread A "gets" false
- Thread B "sets" true
- Thread A computes computes ! false --> true

But: assume that we had a "protected" `getNot()`, the final result would be the **same**:

- Thread A "getNot" false --> true
- Thread B "sets" true

In both cases, the first thread would enter the loop!

Comment: Thank you. I haven't thought that in both cases, the result would be the same.

Answer (score 0):

AtomicBoolean.get is not about being atomic, but instead about being thread-safe.

atomic would be a concept related to read and write stuff, and your question does not mention anything like that.

if you want to read and write (or write and read) atomically, there are other methods on AtomicBoolean (like getAndSet or compareAndSet). From your question it might seem you are looking for something more related to that (cannot tell for sure from your question details).

If what you want is not to retrieve and change a value atomically, but instead retrieve until it is changed in other place of your code after some logic (so not atomically), then you are looking for locking.

Comment: When you follow the javadoc link he has there, and you read what is written in the atomic package, you find: it is very much *also* about atomic "ity".

Comment: which link? the one about "get"? it does not say anything about atomicity. to be clear, i stated that get is not about being atomic; i'm not saying other AtomicInteger methods are not; of coure they are and in fact i mentioned some of them (like compareAndSet)

Comment: The link for atomic boolean, leading to https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/package-summary.html

Comment: you are missing the point of my comment, i know AtomicBoolean is about atomicity. I'm talking about the "get" method which is the one that the OP used. Can you paste the place where it states that "get" is about atomicity? not the AtomicBoolean class, which main purpose for sure it is.

Comment: I guess that part is actually a "misconception" on various ends ... see my answer for my thoughts.

Comment: IMHO: atomicity is about the possibility of performing an operation in "one go" (from the point of view of the caller), so that it's not possible for two threads to obtain intermediate values (temporal let's say). On a get (no matter if AtomicBoolean or not), by definition it is atomic, since there is no write at all so no possible intermediate value. What it could happen if it was not thanks to AtomicBoolean (or others constructs) is that it was not thread-safe or stuff like that and you were not seeing the data you expected because of another thread write not being visible or whatever.